# RMarkdown pdf_document fig.align='center' giving error

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to render this file in RStudio with "Knit PDF".

This code is giving an error for me.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.align = 'center')
```

```{r}
plot(pressure)
```
````

The error

```
output file: test.knit.md

! Undefined control sequence.
l.114 \begin{center}\includegraphics

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Execution halted
```

It seems that `render` is working, but pandoc is giving an error. Is there any problem with my pandoc?

Comment: possibly similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266473/r-knitr-pdf-problems-with-includegraphics

Answer (score 1):

As @hrbrmstr pointed out, Yihui solved it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266473/r-knitr-pdf-problems-with-includegraphics).

The following code works:

````
---
output: pdf_document
graphics: yes
---

```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.align = 'center')
```

```{r}
plot(pressure)
```
````